# OS X Yosemite built-in dictation not working with TeXMaker/TexStudio

Tags: texmaker, texstudio, mac, accessibility

I am writing up my thesis and would like to use the built-in dictation in Mac OS X (10.10) to write.

I am using TeXstudio (and have used TeXmaker also) for writing, but for some reason the OS X built-in dictation, which works for other text boxes in all other applications I've tried so far, doesn't work. When I press the shortcut key (double tap `fn`), I hear a single dull tone, but there is no dictation prompt and voice isn't responded to.

Has anyone experienced/been able to fix this issue? I wonder is it possibly because TeXstudio/maker use QT for the GUI?

Comment: i've added an `[accessibility]` tag because, even though this question does not ask for that reason, that is a major area in which the tool is useful.  (that said, this question might still be considered off topic; though i'm not about to make that call.)

Comment: I think it's exactly because the programs don't use the Apple libraries. Did you try with TeXShop?

Comment: This seems like an issue with the implementation of TeXstudio that we can't really do much about. As a workaround you could do your dictation in the default text editor for OSX and copy-paste it to TeXstudio.

Comment: You need an editor which is based on Cocoa (or whatever Apple has replace Cocoa with if they no longer use that). As egreg says, TeXShop should work but applications based on other technologies won't. That is, you would need to use the QT equivalent of the Cocoa-based dictation facilities for a QT-based editor. (And the editor must be able to use those facilities but the really important thing here is that the editor and the built-in dictation software are based on different frameworks, libraries etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone. That's a shame if it can't be done in TeXstudio itself, as you say it could always be done in another editor then transferred back. In TeXShop it does work. @barbarabeeton, thank you for adding the tag, I hope that it's not off topic, I didn't think so given that it's specific to TeX editing tools.

Answer (score 1):

To get dictation working for TexStudio, go to System Preferences/Accessibility/Dictation Commands and click "Enable advanced commands." For some reason it works when you do that.